# array push 1 value from 2 fields which does not equal variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function which returns a friends list, the only problem is I would like to array push from either wallfriends.mem_id_from or wallfriends.mem_id_to depending on which one is not $user_id.

OR

Can I do it all in SQL?

Does anyone know how i would go abut doing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
function returnFreinds($user_id)
{
    $recget = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM wallusers 
    INNER JOIN wallfriends ON wallusers.mem_id = ".( $user_id == "wallfriends.mem_id_to"?"wallfriends.mem_id_from":"wallfriends.mem_id_to")."
    WHERE ((wallfriends.mem_id_from =".$user_id.") OR (wallfriends.mem_id_to =".$user_id.")) AND wallfriends.confirm=1
    ");

    $friends_list = array();

    if (@mysql_num_rows($recget))
    {
        while ($named = @mysql_fetch_array($recget))
        {
            array_push($friends_list, $named['mem_id']);
        }

        $matches = implode(',', $friends_list);
    }
    else 
        $matches = 0;
    return $matches;
}
```

Comment: "I would like to array push from either wallfriends.mem_id_from or wallfriends.mem_id_to" - could you please further explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you could distinguish at `push`ing in the same manner you've done when constructing the SQL query, maybe something like

```
while ($named = mysql_fetch_array($recget))
{
    array_push($friends_list,
               empty($named['mem_id_to']) ? $named['mem_id_from'] : $named['mem_id_to']
    );
}
```

Also, it's advisable to refrain from suppressing errors with the `@` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right, but how about splitting the query up?

```
( SELECT * FROM wallusers 
  INNER JOIN wallfriends ON wallusers.mem_id = wallfriends.mem_id_from
  WHERE wallfriends.mem_id_to = ". $user_id .")
  AND wallfriends.confirm = 1 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM wallusers 
  INNER JOIN wallfriends ON wallusers.mem_id = wallfriends.mem_id_to
  WHERE wallfriends.mem_id_from = ". $user_id. ")
  AND wallfriends.confirm = 1 )
```